# How to rename a column named 'user' in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a column named `user` in one of the tables. I would like to rename it to `username`, but when I try to run the rename query, psql is saying there is an error in the query. I assume it is because `user` is a keyword in postgres (this is mainly why I want to rename it).

Here is the error I am getting:

```
analytics=# alter table events_to_sync rename column user to username;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "user"
LINE 1: alter table events_to_sync rename column user to username;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`user` is a reserved keyword and thus needs [quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS):

```
alter table events_to_sync rename column "user" to username;
```